# UIButton With Rounded Corner On Top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, calayer

I need a UIButton with backgound image,rounded corner on top and shadow.Here is my code

I tried many post from stack overflow,but none worked for me.

I was able to add UIButton having background image with rounded corners and shadow using following.

```
CALayer *imageLayer = [imageButton layer];
imageLayer.frame =  CGRectMake(110, 190, 100, 100);
imageLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0; 
imageLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
imageLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
imageLayer.shadowRadius = 1;
imageLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(03.0f, 08.0f);
imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;


CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 8);
sublayer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
sublayer.frame = imageLayer.frame;
sublayer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
sublayer.borderWidth = 0.0;
sublayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

[imageButton.layer.superlayer insertSublayer:sublayer atIndex:0];
```

Now How Can I make top corners rounded.

Comment: Why don't you use and image instead of drawings?

Comment: Sorry, but why playing so much around, if you could make a custom button with all needed visual aspects?

Comment: Sorry,I want this feature get implemented by using properties of CALayer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the [ColoredRoundedButton](https://github.com/paulgrayson/ColoredRoundedButton) open source implementation. It uses the `cornerRadius` property of the UIButton's `CALayer` to get rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

To make rounded corner you have to use gradient layer CAGradientLayer.

Answer (score 1):

dont forget

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

if you are using CAGradientLayer